# vector aleatorio de 0s y 1s

Tags: r, rstudio, mutabilidad

soy consciente de que esta es la pregunta más básica que habréis leído por aquí pero me está dando problemas. Estoy haciendo una simulación y para mi conjunto de datos necesito una columna del dataframe que sea dicotómica Y generada aleatoriamente. Para la generación de vectores aleatorios he estado usando

```
sample_size <- 500
categories_no <- 4
cluster_size <- 3
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rep(rnorm(sample_size), each = cluster_size)
```

pero no encuentro código para que dicho vector sea factor. Considerando x1, había pensado aplicar mutate para que aquellos por encima de la media sean 1 y el resto 0, y luego "mezclar" mi vector. Sin embargo no me deja R al decir que es de tipo double, cosa que no consigo cambiar con as.numeric. Así que si alguien sabría hacer algo similar para N dimensiones (para dimensión pequeña sí que consigo generar, pero necesito vectores grandes), lo agradecería bastante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción muy directa es tomar una muestra aleatoria de una distribución binomial:

```
rbinom(n = 2000,   #Cantidad de intentos, el largo del vector resultante
       size = 1,      #Resultados posibles: 1 para dicotómica
       prob = 0.5)    #Probabilidad de éxito o probabilidad de y = 1. 0.5 para que 0 y 1 sean equiprobables.
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada, con una distribución uniforme, puedes generar fácilmente el vector que buscas:

```
sample(1:0, sample_size, replace=TRUE)
```

Ahora, si quieres mantener la lógica del vector aleatorio `x1` y simplemente categorizar los valores por encima o por de bajo de la media, puedes hacer:

```
ifelse(x1<=mean(x1), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Creo que en este caso va con `replace = TRUE` para que pueda llegar al largo necesario.

Comment: Crees bien mpaladino, gracias

Comment: Gracias a ambos! Me estaba bloqueando mucho con esta duda simple, al intentar basarlo en un vector ya generado :)